# SSIS Script task to zip multiple csv fails - the name zipfile does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, ssis, zip

I'm using SSIS and a c# script task.  I want to zip multiple csv files without using any 3rd party applications.

This is my code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Compression;
#endregion

    public void Main()
        {
            {
                string startPath = @"\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\*.csv";
                string zipPath = @"\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\result.zip";              
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);              
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

However, `ZipFile`is being underlines and the error:

> the name zipfile does not exist in the current context

I am basing it from this Microsoft example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

The above article states: If you get the build error "The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context," add a reference to the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly to your project.  But there is no System.IO.Compression.FileSystem within the script editor in SSIS?

Comment: Is the folder name valid?  CAn you get to the folder with Windows Explorer?

Comment: @jdweng I've just put xxxx as I didn't want to put the actual folder paths in

Comment: I know.  It still may not exist which is what I was asking to check.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you dont have the reference to the System.IO.Compression set up correctly.

Just using the statement, `using System.IO.Compression;` does not make System.IO.Compression available, you have to reference the correct dll to your project as well. System.IO.Compression is a .Net assembly that comes with .Net.

- Right-click on the References Folder within your Project (or directly on your Project) in the Solution Explorer.
- Choose Add Reference
- Under the Assemblies or .NET tab, look until you find System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll.
- Select it and Click OK.

*If you are using core, you might need to install it from nuget package.*